# Parsing Multiple Objects from a Single JSON File using JAVA

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have the following json file from which I am trying to extract data and store it to a database.

```
    *//FirstBlockStart*        
    { 
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "572395d8b1bf87f39645b94e"
            },
            "ReferenceDate": {
                "$date": 1461949267500
            },
            "Url": "http://goTechhy.com",
            "PublicationDate": {
                "$date": 1461553200000
            },
            "LastUpdateDate": {
                "$date": 1461553200000
            },

        }
//FirstBlockEnd
//SecondBlockStart
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "572394d8b1bf87f39645b94e"
            },
            "ReferenceDate": {
                "$date": 1461969267500
            },
            "Url": "http://goTechhy.com",
            "PublicationDate": {
                "$date": 1461553200000
            },
            "LastUpdateDate": {
                "$date": 1461353200000
            },

        }
//SecondBlockEnd
```

I need to extract the `Oid, ReferenceData, PublicationData, LastUpdateDate` from the JSON

Here is what I have tried.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        JSONObject Obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("E:\\Json2Db\\PlayStore1.json")));
        //JSONObject Obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("E:\\Json2Db\\PlayStore1.json"));


        getAppID(Obj);

        System.out.println(getAppID(Obj));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getAppID(JSONObject obj) {
    JSONObject appIDObj = (JSONObject) obj.get("_id");
    String appID = (String) appIDObj.get("$oid");
    return appID;
}
```

When I try to execute this code, I get the following error.

```
Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 4644.
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:146)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
    at com.freelancer.kaja.JsonParse.main(JsonParse.java:18)
```

But at the same time, When there is only One Block (say FirstBlock) in JSON, it works fine.. I am new to this JSON thing.. I dont know what I am missing here.. Please give your suggestions.

I would like the output to be something like this.

```
oid: 572395d8b1bf87f39645b94e
ReferenceDate:1461949267500
Url:http://goTechhy.com
PublicationDate:1461553200000
LastUpdateDate: 1461553200000

oid: 572395d8b1bf87f39645b94e
ReferenceDate:1461949267500
Url:http://goTechhy.com
PublicationDate:1461553200000
LastUpdateDate: 1461553200000
```

Comment: hi !its a good question.

Comment: Well, a proper JSON file should contain only one JSON object/array (which may have data in it). Yours has three separate objects. So it's not really a proper JSON file - you should split it and parse the objects separately.

Comment: @RealSkeptic How three Objects?

Comment: Each of your "blocks" is a single JSON object.

Comment: Or you can separate them with commas and add square brackets around the whole thing to make it an array.